# App recreates itself everytime I change a child value in firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am facing a really frustrating problem and would be grateful if you could give me a tip here. I am creating an app using firebase database. The problem is that I have a child node called (everyone); inside of (everyone) there are 4 subchildren keys having values -- it looks like this:

```
everyone
|
|-name: jim
 -haircolor: black
 -height: 175cm
 -hobbies: none
```

Now (everyone) node is used by all other activities in my app and I listen to this node using ValueEventListener.

The problem shows up when I try to edit a certain subchild. For example if I want to edit (name), the editing will cause my app to recreate itself over and over. The subchildren's values are edited in firebase console and I have no problem with that; where the only problem is the recreating loop of my app's mainactivity. I don't really know the cause as nothing is appearing on the LOG CAT because the app doesn't crash, it only recreates itself giving this: (startactivity called from non-activity context).

Sorry I didn't post any other code because there are too many files and I don't wehre the problem is arising from. I am predicting that when onchildchanged is called in other activities' ValueEventListener something is happening.. Other than this I am clueless.

Thank you for your time that you have spent reading this.

Answer (score 0):

when you update a value in everyone node, all the listeners attached to that node will be called since the listener is `valueEventListener`. yo need to put checks in on data change to see which activity should process the change.
Also I'm assuming all activities are running i.e. no activity has called finished.

Comment: Hi Umar. Thank you. Can you explain what you mean by "you need to put checks in on data change"? Can you give me a quick example to understand what you mean? Thank you.

Comment: ok sure but please first expain what you are currently doing inside onDatachange method ? which is causing the app to crash? or add the code to your question for better understanding.

Comment: well basically I get the subchildren using datasnapshot and then I set them to textviews using set text method ((All I do is get and set the values)). Umar as I said I don't know where the problem is arising from and my code files are so many so I can't put just any file without knowing which file is causing the problem.

Comment: this crashes your app ?

Comment: The problem is when I change a value in subchildren, it recreates itself and it does NOT crash.

Comment: atleast post one value event listener otherwise its not clear why this happens.

Comment: one  other thing you can do is only listen for value event in one activity only and then use broadcast in your app to tell other activities about the changes since you are only setting the text.

Comment: One more thing I am using recyclerview and I have many module classes and I am refering to the (everyone) also from the viewholder in recycleradapter method. and listening to changes in the (everyone ) is widely used in my app .

Comment: But what may cause the recreating of the app Iam confused , why a change in values is re opening the entire app over and over